# link_to white remote => true throws a 406 error on IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, prototype

I've a very big problem when updating to rails 3.

If I use this:

```
= link_to "Show Parent Text", show_parent_path(c.id), :remote => true, :method => :get
```

It works great at Firefox and the controller responds normaly:

```
respond_to  do |format|
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html "original_#{@h.id}", :partial => "texts/original"
    end
  end
end
```

But Internet Explorer 9 handles the link with a GET request to show_parent_path(c.id) instead of using the AJAX request, resulting in a 406 error page.

How can I fix this? I'm having this issue with Rails 3.0.5. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Any chance you can post the generated HTML? It's a bit difficult to understand what isn't working without seeing the code that is sent to the browser.

Comment: Maybe you have some error in javascript? Is js console clear?

Comment: I'm assuming you're certain that Javascript is enabled in the IE you're using? Does your script throw any JS errors? *Side note*: Since a GET request is default for links, you shouldn't need to define the method here.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occurred having an error in the JavaScript code. Eliminating this worked for me.
Maybe this helps you, too?